# php create html-table with unknown amount of columns in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mariadb, unexpectendoffile

i want to create an html table from a mariadb database. I dont know how many columns each Database table will end up with.

So as i dont know how many columns i have, i came up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
//query
    $sql="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY author";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);



    $counter = 0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        echo $counter;
        echo nl2br("\n");
        ?>  

        <table>
            <thead>
                <?php       
                if($counter==0){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo implode("</th><th>", array_keys($row)); ?>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    }
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php       
                if($counter>=0){ ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo implode("</td><td>", $row); ?>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <?php
        $counter ++;
    }

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the table wont fill with more than the first row.

Additionally i have get the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in E:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 58
>   Blockquote

The Error disappears when i enter two curly braces "}}" after the while loop, it will present the following:

[execute:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82YSB.png)

I dont know why there are the curly braces in the browser as seen in the picture.

**EDIT**: I edit the thread because it was marked as duplicate to  [parsing and syntax errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them), though my main problem is the creation of the table with unknown number of columns.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you guys!

Comment: Start by only putting what you want repeated multiple times INSIDE the while loop

Comment: Start by separating your code and your HTML, and indent properly. Then you will easily be able to spot your typo.

Comment: Yes thank you, i always try to do everything inside one big loop, need to practise on that thinking.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure why it was giving that error, as all your braces were closed. However, try simplifying -- as RiggsFolly said, put only what you want repeated inside the loop. It makes your logic much simpler and neater. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
//query
    $sql="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY author";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
    ?>

    <table>
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo implode("</th><th>", array_keys($row)); ?>
                    </th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo implode("</td><td>", $row); ?>
                </td>
                </tr>

    <?php
    $counter = 0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
//        echo $counter;
//        echo nl2br("\n");
        ?>  

                <tr>
                <td><?php echo implode("</td><td>", $row); ?>
                </td>
                </tr>

        <?php
        $counter ++;
    }

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And then, check out any of the free [template processors](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=php+template+processor) available, so you're not mixing content and code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, especially pointing out to the template engines (as i am a total beginner is very nice to know). I can see one big error came from not setting the fetched array free inside the table.